# 'UnknownError' on indexedDB.open in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb

I'm having a very basic failure in using indexedDB. Running in current Firefox (56.0, 64-bit), but I've been seeing this problem for some time.

The following rather simple HTML/Javascript demonstrates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>indexedDB simple test</title>
<script src="/fb/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<script> 
    try {
        if ('indexedDB' in window) {
            $('#wrapper').append('Has native indexedDB<br />'); 
        } else {
            indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
            IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
            IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;
            $('#wrapper').append('Has indexedDB, but not native<br />'); 
        }
        if (indexedDB) {
            var ver = 1;
            if ( ! 'open' in indexedDB ) {
                $('#wrapper').append('indexedDB.open doesn\'t exist.<br />');
            }
            if ( typeof indexedDB.open != 'function' ) {
                $('#wrapper').append('indexedDB.open is not a function.<br />');
            }
            try {
                var request = indexedDB.open("foo", ver);
            } catch (ex) {
                $('#wrapper').append('indexedDB.open threw error.<br />');
            }
        }
    } catch (ex) {
    }
</script> 
</body>
```

`indexedDB` shows as native; `indexedDB.open` shows as an existing function; but when it's called, the Web Console shows 'UnknownError' at   indexed_db_simple_test.html:28:30. I have no idea what might be wrong.

Comment: Further thought: `request` does get a value set, but that value shows an `error` element with `error.name == 'UnknownError'`

Comment: _"The following rather simple HTML/Javascript demonstrates the problem:"_ --- Uhm... the only IndexedDB commandin there are two lines of code, the rest is not needed for an example. We really don't need all your GUI candy - unless you were to make it into an executable code sample that can be run right here, which SO allows you to do.... And I don't get any error when I paste that line in the FF console, not directly, not on `request.error`. You also should not need the "||"" assignments if you target modern browsers, I think.

Comment: Please include the code where you call indexedDB.open

Comment: @Josh It is inside the try/catch.

Comment: More issues with your code: `indexedDB`, `IDBTransaction`, `IDBKeyRange` are global variables, and don't use `var` any more (at all), use `let` and `const`. `var` is hoisted to the top of the function, let/const allow better (block-level) control over where that variable should exist, and `const` helps the runtime to optimize. The `if` that checks if `open` is a function nevertheless allows the code to continue even if it isn't. You only need the `typeof` check, the preceding `if` is redundant. Optional: Since you use `try` you don't need any `if` check.

Comment: Finally, you have a global try/catch with an empty catch statement -- at the very least log errors, now they are silently discarded!

Comment: Even more: The _"Has native indexedDB"_ output is not quite right, the `else` branch would be useless if there wasn't "native indexedDB" - you don't polyfill it, the alternative path still is "native". If you target browsers after  Internet Explorer 10, Firefox 16, Chrome 24 you don't need that entire first `if` at all. Regarding your use of globals, look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB -- at least make your intent that it should be on `window` clear by assigning to `window.indexedDB` (etc.).

Comment: I was paring down inherited code. Yes, I could have pared further. I left code in place that demonstrates that the error it throws is not because the function is nonexistent, etc. 

The point remains: why does it give `UnknownError`?

Comment: For me `window.indexedDB.open('test')` firing `Unknow Error`. On Firefox ESR latest version.

Comment: "UnknownError" is usually indicative of an internal error in the implementation - i.e. you're not doing anything wrong, but the underlying database file is corrupt or something.

Try clearing browsing data for the origin you're trying, or test in a different origin (e.g. if you're testing against localhost:8000 try localhost:8001 which might use a different backing store)

Comment: Very interesting. Is there any way to clear indexedDB without also clearing localStorage? There's data there I don't want to lose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been dealing with this issue for a couple days now.  In our case, we've found the issue is with users using Firefox ESR, it seems somehow when profiles get mangled from upgrades it makes indexedDB not work correctly.  The fix we found is to use this command to create a new profile:

`$ /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P`

If that indeed fixes your problem, then you can see it mentioned here in a firefox issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246615

For more info on that profile command see the docs: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Our current solution to not just have the app blow up is to do a feature check which is basically like this:

```
var DBOpenRequest = window.indexedDB.open('someDb');

DBOpenRequest.onerror = function(event) {
  window.location.href = '/unsupported_browser.html';
};
```

We're also asking users to fix their profiles as well to enable usage of our app (which relies on indexedDB to work).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Seems like good advice in general. I will follow you on how not to actually fire an error, but I think there is near zero chance of convincing our thousands of users to create new profiles.

Comment: Quick update, in Chrome when in incognito mode this DBOpenRequest actually seems to block the redirect for about 10 seconds, so I added this to my test:

Comment: DBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
    event.target.result.close();
}